# Enable DRCP in Weblogic 12c fails

Tags: oracle, jdbc, datasource, weblogic12c

I'm trying to create a data source enabled with DRCP in Weblogic 12c installed in Linux. After providing all required values & 'Test Configuration' there is an error (cited below ). I have tried the same on Windows and it worked for same port number (also included SERVER=POOLED in 'tnsnames.ora' for client purpose in Windows).

Configurations:

1. Linux machine : Weblogic 12c (12.1.2)
2. URL : jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.125.158.115:1521/PERF01:POOLED
3. oracle.jdbc.DRCPConnectionClass = myDRCPClass

Error:

```
<AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1432019762569> 
<BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: 
IO Error: Invalid number format for port number
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:465)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:232)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:280)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:469)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:156)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:101)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.testConnection0(DataSourceUtil.java:356)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.access$000(DataSourceUtil.java:22)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil$1.run(DataSourceUtil.java:254)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.testConnection(DataSourceUtil.java:251)
    .
    .
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Invalid number format for port number
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveSimple(AddrResolution.java:512)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:409)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the normal drive class `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`? You can still create connection pools with that driver. And then possibly changing `PERF01:POOLED` to `PERF01`.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..i have tried creating using normal driver class & that works, able to connect but i want to create a data source with DRCP enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Change of Weblogic version (from Weblogic 12.1.2 to 12.1.3) solved this problem. Both Weblogic 12.1.1 & Weblogic 12.1.3 supports DRCP.